# select between two many-to-many relations

Tags: sql, sql-server, many-to-many, self-join

I have four tables Level, Tag, Level_Tag and Tag_hierarchy. How can select **all tags of a level which have this condition id_tag = id_parent** which means the Tag is the root. I can select from join table (Maybe not a good performance?) but I don't know how to add the other self join here.

```
SELECT        level.name, tag.id, tag.name
FROM            level INNER JOIN
                         tag_level ON level.id = tag_level.id_level INNER JOIN
                         tag ON tag_level.id_tag = tag.id
WHERE        (level.Id =  @id)
```

Tag Table contains thousands of rows and I'm really worry about memory and performance issues.
Could you please help me on this? Here is the schema

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
;with cte as
(select id_tag
 from tag_hierarchy where id_tag = id_parent)

select l.name, t.id, t.name
from cte c
inner join tag t on t.id = c.id_tag
inner join tag_level tl on t.id = tl.id_tag
inner join level l on tl.id_level = l.id
where l.lid = @id
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can add another exists. Like this:

```
SELECT        
    level.name, 
    tag.id, 
    tag.name
FROM            
    level 
    INNER JOIN tag_level 
        ON level.id = tag_level.id_level 
    INNER JOIN tag 
        ON tag_level.id_tag = tag.id
WHERE        
    (level.Id =  @id)
    AND EXISTS
    (
        SELECT NULL 
        FROM Tag_hierarchy
        WHERE  Tag_hierarchy.id_tag=tag.id
        AND Tag_hierarchy.id_tag=Tag_hierarchy.id_parent
    )
```

Comment: Thanks Arion for your answer. I think both answers are almost the same and I chose the the other one because it was posted earlier.